# Why does command module hang for ansible for psql?

Tags: postgresql, ansible, psql

When I issue the `psql` command like this in my playbook:

```
- name: Run psql to pull in initial config data
  become_method: sudo
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  command: psql -U postgres -w eclaim < /opt/eclaim_revamp/sql_scripts/initial_config.sql
```

It takes forever to complete, looks as though hang, but when I use `shell`, it can get through:

```
- name: Run psql to pull in initial data
  become_method: sudo
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  shell: psql -U postgres -w eclaim < /opt/eclaim_revamp/sql_scripts/initial_sql_script.sql
```

Can anybody tell me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html):

> [The given command] will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", and "&" will not work (use the shell module if you need these features).

Comment: To add on why that is resulting in the observed behavior, the commands aren't fed in through the input file, and so Postgres is just waiting for input.